# How can I know if the user tampered with the CSS or JavaScript to change the appearance of my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

In other words, can I know if somebody uses script or CSS extension tools?

For example, he aligned things differently, placed `display: none;` on several elements, used jQuery's `.hasClass` to add or remove divs?

Comment: You can't, really. There's a really obnoxious way to check current styles within javascript (check the amount of visible divs, for example) but those can be avoided as well if the user wants to tamper the code anyway.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y question. Is there a reason you need to do this? The user can amend whatever they want to and there's nothing you can do to stop this. So long as you have good user input validation on the server side, then there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so as well.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thanks for the reply. I'm making a quiz site and I'm worried of potential meddling.

Comment: In that case you need to validate all user input on the server. That way it doesn't matter what is changed on the client

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm assuming the quiz is client-side only, in that case: Your best guess would to obfuscate / minify / hexify your code. Doesn't give a 100% foolproof safe, but will filter out 95% of the culprits.

Comment: Well, you can try rendering the site as an image on the server, jk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any one-shot, easy, "Hey, they modified the page" way. You'd have to have a record of exactly what elements you were expecting to be on the page, and their effective CSS properties, and then check all of those at runtime against the actual DOM and the effective CSS properties of the elements in the DOM.

It's going to be prohibitively complicated and hard to maintain.

Comment: Not to mention impossible if you're using 3rd party content like a facebook like box, which displays content you're not controlling, and is therefor even harder to check.

Comment: @Roberrrt: Yeah, you'd have to skip those.

Comment: I'm _assuming_ (which is very, very bad practice) OP wants a subtle way to detect adblockers. Would make the entire situation more complicated, since it blocks certain third party content.